# Why rz of lrzsz package upload file failed with char disordered

Tags: file-upload, locale, file-transfer, zmodem, xshell

I always upload to remote server use rz of lrzsz package like this `rz -bey`.

But it's failed randomly with `character gibberish`(fill the screen with unknown character), not every time. And the upload is terminated. I must close the XShell Session and open a new one.

I googled and find out that almost all of the solutions use the option `-be`. Some solution told that you should change the locale variable `LC_CTYPE`.

But it does not work for me.

Thanks for your Suggestion.